# CSS break table and repeat first column

Tags: html, css

I am modifying a website that currently uses a `<table>` for a price list.

[image: Table]

Because tables obviously don't break + wrap, on a mobile device the right hand side of the table disappears of the right side of the screen.

I'd like to use CSS to make this price list responsive, so that when the browser runs out of width it renders the next column underneath. This is simple enough if I stop using a single table and use `float:left`, but in this case I want the name of the cottage to be repeated (the first column) when a horizontal break occurs.

[image: Mobile - wrapped]

Is this possible? If so, how would I achieve it?

Comment: You can use bootstrap for colspans : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/ Also should use reponsive grids with just HTML and CSS : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp

Comment: Could you show us your current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, a better way to construct this to do what your aiming for is not to use the Table element at all.

Instead, use a series of div elements and give them the display type "table-cell" on the individual divs, along with "display: table" and "display: table-row" where needed for for rows and the overall table.

See: http://www.senktec.com/2014/01/using-css-display-table-cell-for-columns/

For an example.

Once you've broken things down into indidvidual div's, your then free to place those divs where you see fit, You could with a little bit of re-layout in the structure of the divs, put a new set down below the the first part of the table as you mention in your question.

However, once your using div elements, this actually opens up a more interesting way of doing things, by using FlexBox and more specifically "flex-wrap".

Flexbox and it's wrapping modes will do exactly what your trying to achieve, you just need to make the parent container "display: flex", add a flex wrap css rule, and the immediate div children of the container will take care of themselves.

Flexbox is fully supported by ALL mainstream browsers these days, and the various table display modes have been around since HTML4, so your not going to have an issue with any of it working.  Flex also largely works on IE11, with a few minor edge cases (I implemented an online designer for a company 3 years ago when flexbox was first introduced and the target was IE11).

With the individual div approach, and if your targeting reasonable recent browsers you can actually go one step further and use CSS media queries to adjust things for different display widths

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

and you can even now do some feature detection is CSS too

https://css-tricks.com/using-feature-detection-to-write-css-with-cross-browser-support/

The only thing I can't come up with a possible solution for in pure CSS is the repeating of the cottage names column, although I suspect you might actually be able to conjure something up using "data attributes" and css rules targeting those attributes to get the text of the column name into an "element::before" pseudo css rule of some kind, I'd need to sit and spend a day playing with that idea to come up with anything concrete though.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any time Peter, glad it was of some help to you. :-)